# AVFoundation record video in MP4 format

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, mp4

I am using AVFoundation to record video on IOS 5.  I would like the content to be in an MP4 container.  I have been searching around and cannot find a message that specifies the format to record the video in.  I would rather record to the MP4 file on the first shot instead of recording it to a mov file and then reencode it in a mp4 on a separate pass.  Does anyone know how to do this?

I guessed above when I said it records to a mov.  What is the default file format it records to?

I am new with AVFoundation and IOS in general so please excuse me if some of this is obvious and I am having difficulty finding it.

Thankyou for any help

Comment: You have asked this question 5 years ago and probably solved it by using asssetwrier. Do you know what you are asking is possible without assetwriter in 2017 ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently unaware of how to do it in foundation classes, but you can certainly do it using [AVAssetWriter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAssetWriter/shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse) look for option outputFileType and shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse.

Comment: thank you, my understanding of this class is that AVFoundation creates the orginal media file, then this reads it, encodes it in a different format and writes it back to storage.  Is this true? I would like to avoid all this additional overhead if possible.

Comment: Till now I haven't found the way to avoid this overhead.