# How do I encode iOS videos as .mp4 from UIImagePickerController so that Android devices can play them?

Tags: android, ios, ffmpeg, mp4, mov

I am using UIImagePickerController to record short (<30s) videos which are then saved and uploaded via our API. The app is cross-platform and so I need recorded videos to be encoded into mp4 format so that Android devices can play them.

I used instructions from the following questions to create my solution:

[Swift - How to record video in MP4 format with UIImagePickerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354689/swift-how-to-record-video-in-mp4-format-with-uiimagepickercontroller)

[AVFoundation record video in MP4 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814997/avfoundation-record-video-in-mp4-format)

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/94762

I record my video through the UIImagePickerController like so:

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    // Local variable inserted by Swift 4.2 migrator.
    let info = convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(info)


    let videoNSURL = info[convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL)] as? NSURL

    videoURL = videoNSURL!.absoluteURL
    if let videoURL = videoURL {
        let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL, options: nil)

        avAsset.exportVideo { (exportedURL) in
            if let uploadVC = self.uploadVC {
                uploadVC.incomingFileURL = exportedURL
                uploadVC.myJewelleryID = self.myJewelleryID
                uploadVC.topicID = self.topicID
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
              //Update UI with results from previous closure
                self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                self?.showUploadContainer()
                self?.updateVideoContainerWithURL(url: exportedURL)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This then passes the exported MP4 url to the upload container view, where it saves the file to the device:

```
private func saveVideoFileToDevice() {

    //Filename Struct = [AssetID]_[TopicID]_[CustomerID]_[Datestamp]
    let date = Date()
    let formater = DateFormatter()
    formater.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formater.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"

    uploadFileName = ""
    if let mjID = myJewelleryID {
        uploadFileName = "ASID_\(mjID)_\(User.instance.customerID)_\(formater.string(from: date)).mp4"
    } else if let tID = topicID {
        uploadFileName = "ASID_\(tID)_\(User.instance.customerID)_\(formater.string(from: date)).mp4"
    }

    let fileManager = FileManager.default

    if let destURL = URL(string: "file://\(NSHomeDirectory())/Documents/\(uploadFileName!)") {

        var fileData: Data!
        print("destURL = \(destURL)")
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItem(at: incomingFileURL! as URL, to: destURL)
            fileData = try Data(contentsOf: incomingFileURL! as URL)

            try fileData.write(to: destURL)


        }
        catch {
            print("DEBUG: Failed to save video data")
        }
    }
}
```

and then uploads the file to our API.  Although the file is MP4, it does not play on Android.  On inspection, the file looks very similar to a file that will actually play on an Android device when we compare the codec data:

[image: Screenshot of codec comparison]

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var exportSession: AVAssetExportSession!


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            
        guard let videoURL = (info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL) else { return }
        encodeVideo(videoURL)
    }

func encodeVideo(_ videoURL: URL)  {
        let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL, options: nil)
        
        //Create Export session
        exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: avAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough)
        
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] as URL
        let filePath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("rendered-Video.mp4")
        deleteFile(filePath)
        
        exportSession!.outputURL = filePath
        exportSession!.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
        exportSession!.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        let start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, preferredTimescale: 0)
        let range = CMTimeRangeMake(start: start, duration: avAsset.duration)
        exportSession.timeRange = range
        
        exportSession!.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {() -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                Utility.stopActivityIndicator()
                
                switch self.exportSession!.status {
                case .failed:
                    self.view.makeToast(self.exportSession?.error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                case .cancelled:
                    self.view.makeToast("Export canceled")
                case .completed:
                    if let url = self.exportSession.outputURL {
                        //Rendered Video URL
                    }
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Delete File function:

```
func deleteFile(_ filePath: URL) {
        guard FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath.path) else {
            return
        }
        
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: filePath.path)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Unable to delete file: \(error) : \(#function).")
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to import AVFoundation

Hope that will help!

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am already using a similar method (the exportVideo extension posted below by Harry).  Unfortunately, although the video transcodes to mp4, the resulting file cannot be played on an Android device.  It is very infuriating!

Comment: Above coded is tried and tested you can give it a try and check once. I am using the above code in https://apps.apple.com/us/app/we-rockstar/id1459404484?ls=1

Comment: hi, i got this problem ***[Error: convert failed for Users/thehe/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A69D905C-4531-438C-9123-85D8EE81EC54/data/Containers/Data/Application/06CC0F2D-3D96-4734-8AAB-05816F14F6B7/tmp/com.vedax.vedaxlinkv2-Inbox/IMG_1668.mp4.MOV, error: The operation could not be completed]***, i just copy your code, can u help?

Comment: i debug on xcode then found this error ***figAssetExportSession_IsAssetPropertyAvailable signalled err=-12939 (loadingError) (AssetProperty Failed to load) at FigAssetExportSession.c:4782***

Answer (score 1):

```
//MARK:- Convert iPhoneVideo(.mov) to mp4
extension AVURLAsset
{
    func exportVideo(presetName: String = AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality, outputFileType: AVFileType = .mp4, fileExtension: String = "mp4", then completion: @escaping (URL?) -> Void)
    {
        let filename = url.deletingPathExtension().appendingPathExtension(fileExtension).lastPathComponent
        let outputURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(filename)

    if let session = AVAssetExportSession(asset: self, presetName: presetName) {
        session.outputURL = outputURL
        session.outputFileType = outputFileType
        let start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.0, preferredTimescale: 0)
        let range = CMTimeRangeMake(start: start, duration: duration)
        session.timeRange = range
        session.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
        session.exportAsynchronously {
            switch session.status {
            case .completed:
                completion(outputURL)
            case .cancelled:
                debugPrint("Video export cancelled.")
                completion(nil)
            case .failed:
                let errorMessage = session.error?.localizedDescription ?? "n/a"
                debugPrint("Video export failed with error: \(errorMessage)")
                completion(nil)
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    } else {
        completion(nil)
    }
}
}


//MARK:- ImagePicker delegate methods
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
    {

if let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL {

                let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: nil)
            avAsset.exportVideo(presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality, outputFileType: AVFileType.mp4, fileExtension: "mp4") { (mp4Url) in
                print("Mp4 converted url : \(String(describing: mp4Url))")
                self.videoPath = mp4Url//videoURL//

            }

}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I meant to add that this extension is the method I have been using to convert the video to mp4.  The exportVideo method gets called when the UIImagePickerController has got a video file.  The resulting encoded video looks like a valid mp4 - but for some reason it will not play on Android devices.  I am stumped!